# java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id -1

Tags: android, android-view, android-tablayout, illegalstateexception

I found the following crash log in **crashlytics** for Lenovo K50a40, OS 6.0 and few more devices. I am not able to trace the exception from this log, could not find any clue where this exception came from my app. I didn't find anyone in the community who have faced similar issue earlier. Kindly share your insights if you have some knowledge of it.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id -1: android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19199)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1275)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:650)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$SlidingTabStrip.onMeasure(TabLayout.java:1859)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1259)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:315)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.onMeasure(TabLayout.java:1030)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onMeasure(AppBarLayout.java:234)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:719)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1008)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:787)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:789)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:786)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:560)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:786)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:560)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6124)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2747)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19169)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2485)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1444)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1698)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1325)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6741)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:912)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:714)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:649)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:898)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Would be  helpful if you post your layouts -  it seems that there is some problem with them.

Comment: similar issue would be like this, 

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id 2131296511: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()

Comment: Please add `setMeasuredDimension()` in `onMeasure()`. And if you're using Fragment, ensure you have this line: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: As previous anwers suggest it seems that you didn't specify measure dimensions in some GUI item, here is a description of very similar issue https://books.google.ru/books?id=2xhKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=android+%22View+with+id+-1%22&source=bl&ots=vlu-6NNbd_&sig=cM6bjsskNlmVPObDe7f8AQXm2b8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj40JuztdLZAhVPKywKHdmHBDoQ6AEIVTAF#v=onepage&q=android%20%22View%20with%20id%20-1%22&f=false

Comment: What are the gradle dependencies that you are using for `TabLayout`.

Comment: @ReazMurshed android support library, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting **Width** and **Height** for **Tab**:

The calls `MeasureSpec.getSize()` or `MeasureSpec.getMode()` in `onMeasure()` method may throw `RuntimeException()` if Width\Height is missing.

```
@Override    
public void onMeasure(final int origWidthMeasureSpec, final int origHeightMeasureSpec) {
    final int specWidthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(origWidthMeasureSpec);
    final int specWidthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(origWidthMeasureSpec);
    final int maxWidth = getTabMaxWidth();
    ...
}
```